# Not able to get the stored procedure's result in variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables

i have a Hierarchy of stored procedures calling one in another as below:

```
1
 2
  3
```

Now what i am doing is: 
first of all i am showing the 3rd level sp which is least level.

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateOnly] 
(      
@Scheduleid bigint=258,                            
@Contactid uniqueidentifier='EDE3E474-02CA-49C7-86DD-AA97794ECF8A',                                     
@ScheduleDate datetime= '2012-07-16 00:00:00.000',                                    
@StartTime varchar(20)='12:03:00.0000000',                                    
@EndTime varchar(20)='15:00:00.0000000',                                    
@Location bigint=8,                                    
@Area bigint=7,                                    
@Room bigint=9,                        
@Enddate datetime='2012-07-16 00:00:00.000',                    
@CurrentTime Datetime='2012-07-16 12:00:35.900',      
@ModifiedBy uniqueidentifier='0BF84A77-FAC2-44E5-AF9B-39740415DBD2',                  
@schedulefileidNew bigint=''         
)      
as      
Declare @schedulefileid bigint      
if @schedulefileidNew=0                
 begin                
   set @schedulefileid=null                
 end                
else                
 begin                
set @schedulefileid=@schedulefileidNew                
end       
update tblUserScheduleNew   set Contactid=@Contactid,      
ScheduleDate =@ScheduleDate,      
StartTime = @StartTime,      
EndTime =@EndTime,      
Location =@Location,      
Area=@Area,      
Room =@Room,      
LastModifiedDate=@CurrentTime ,EndDate=@Enddate,      
ModifiedBy=@ModifiedBy,      
ScheduleFileId=@schedulefileid      
where ScheduleId=@Scheduleid and IsDeleted=0 and isActive=1      
select 1
```

Now the second level :

```
CREATE Proc [dbo].[proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate]
(          
@StartDatePassed datetime='8/2/2012 12:00:00 AM',       
@EndDatePassed datetime='8/2/2012 12:00:00 AM', --='2012-07-11 00:00:00.000',          
@StartTimePassed varchar(20)='13:00:00',--='02:00:00.0000000',          
@EndTimePassed varchar(20)='21:00:00',--='03:00:00.0000000',          
@CurrentDateTime Datetime ='8/1/2012 5:50:31 AM', --='2012-07-11 02:07:35.900'          
@Scheduleid bigint=0x0000000000000166,          
@Contactid uniqueidentifier='77680636-bc4b-4489-9cec-3bc000ffe773',          
@Location bigint=11,          
@Area bigint=10,          
@Room bigint=11,          
@ModifiedBy uniqueidentifier='acf7961c-4111-49ad-a66a-ce7f9ce131bd',          
@schedulefileidNew bigint=null         
)          
as  
declare @ResultForInsertUpdate varchar(200);  
if CONVERT(date,@StartDatePassed,101)>CONVERT(date,@CurrentDateTime,101) and     
CONVERT(date,@EndDatePassed,101)>CONVERT(date,@CurrentDateTime,101) and
 CONVERT(date,@EndDatePassed,101)>CONVERT(date,@StartDatePassed,101)           
  begin -- it will run when the Start date and end date passed are greater than Current date and EndDate is greater than Start date.          
Print 'Update'          
exec @ResultForInsertUpdate =  dbo.proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateOnly @Scheduleid,@Contactid,@StartDatePassed,@StartTimePassed,@EndTimePassed,@Location,@Area,@Room,@EndDatePassed,@CurrentDateTime,@ModifiedBy,@schedulefileidNew          
select @ResultForInsertUpdate;  
  end          
else
begin
select 2
end
```

Now the 3rd and final level

```
Alter Proc proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateWithAllRoomsOption
(
@StartDatePassed datetime='2013-04-29 00:00:00.000',
@EndDatePassed datetime='2013-04-29 00:00:00.000',
@StartTimePassed varchar(20)='15:00:00',
@EndTimePassed varchar(20)='20:00:00',
@CurrentDateTime Datetime ='2013-04-25 00:00:00.000',
@Scheduleid bigint=1,
@Contactid uniqueidentifier='FD3E0DDF-8B91-493F-94DF-B8280AC33BC0',
@Location bigint=17,
@Area bigint=0,
@Room bigint=0,
@ModifiedBy uniqueidentifier='ACF7961C-4111-49AD-A66A-CE7F9CE131BD',
@schedulefileidNew bigint=null,
@OldStartDate Datetime='2013-04-26 00:00:00.000',
@OldEndDate DateTime='2013-04-26 00:00:00.000',
@OldStartTime varchar(20)='11:11:11.0000000',
@OldEndTime varchar(20)='22:22:22.0000000',
@OldContactid uniqueidentifier='DA101C1D-45A1-4F9A-B19B-4E88DDE01B10',
@OldLocation bigint=18,
@OldArea bigint=17,
@OldRoom bigint=22
)
as
-- declare variables Starts here       
declare @row_count int;        
DECLARE @intFlag INT=0;      
declare @locationIdForLoop bigint  ;      
declare @AreaIdForLoop bigint  ;      
declare @RoomIdForLoop bigint  ;   
DECLARE @ResultForInsertUpdate INT      
set @ResultForInsertUpdate=1;
-- declare tempraroy table to store location, Area and rooms Starts here      
CREATE TABLE  #tempTable (      
RowNum int,        
LocationId bigint,
AreaId bigint,
RoomId bigint
)
-- declare tempraroy table to store location, Area and rooms Ends here
if @Area=0 and @Room=0
begin
insert into #tempTable (RowNum,LocationId,AreaId,RoomId) (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
(ORDER BY LocationId desc) RowNum, LocationId,AreaId,RoomId from
tblroomnew where areaid in(select Areaid from tblareanew where locationid=@Location))
set @row_count=(select count(*) from #tempTable)
SET @intFlag = 1
WHILE (@intFlag <=@row_count)
BEGIN
-- Do what ever you want to do here
set @locationIdForLoop=(select locationid from #tempTable where RowNum=@intFlag)
set @AreaIdForLoop=(select areaid from #tempTable where RowNum=@intFlag)
set @RoomIdForLoop=(select roomid from #tempTable where RowNum=@intFlag)
if @ResultForInsertUpdate=1
begin
if exists(select 1 from tbluserschedulenew where 
convert(datetime,ScheduleDate,101)=convert(datetime,@OldStartDate,101) and
Convert(datetime,EndDate,101)=convert(datetime,@OldEndDate,101) and 
convert(Time,StartTime,108)=convert(Time,@OldStartTime,108) and
convert(Time,EndTime,108) =convert(Time,@OldEndTime,108) and contactid=@OldContactid 
and
Location=@OldLocation and Area=@OldArea and Room=@OldRoom )
begin
Print 'Update First record'
exec @ResultForInsertUpdate = proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate @StartDatePassed,@EndDatePassed,@StartTimePassed,@EndTimePassed,@CurrentDateTime,@Scheduleid,@Contactid,
@locationIdForLoop,@AreaIdForLoop,@RoomIdForLoop,@ModifiedBy,@schedulefileidNew
--set @ResultForInsertUpdate=1
print @ResultForInsertUpdate
--select @ResultForInsertUpdate
end
else
begin
print 'insert karna hai record'
exec  proc_tblUserScheduleNewLatestInsert @Contactid,@StartDatePassed,@StartTimePassed,@EndTimePassed,
@locationIdForLoop,@AreaIdForLoop,@RoomIdForLoop, @EndDatePassed,@ModifiedBy,0,@CurrentDateTime
--print @ResultForInsertUpdate
end
end
else
begin
select @ResultForInsertUpdate
end
SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
end
else
begin
if @Area!=0 and @Room=0
begin
insert into #tempTable (RowNum,LocationId,AreaId,RoomId) (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LocationId desc) RowNum, LocationId,AreaId,RoomId from
tblroomnew where areaid =@Area)
set @row_count=(select count(*) from #tempTable)
end
else
begin
print 'chalan do jo chal reha'
exec proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate @StartDatePassed,@EndDatePassed,@StartTimePassed,@EndTimePassed,@CurrentDateTime,@Scheduleid,@Contactid,
 @location,@Area,@Room,@ModifiedBy,@schedulefileidNew
--print 'simple update'
end
end
```

Now what is my problem:

I am selecting 1 as result in 3rd level which will stored in "**@ResultForInsertUpdate**" in second level and in 3rd level again..

I am getting 0 in @ResultForInsertUpdate i dont know why, please help me to resolve this prob

Comment: please comment downvotersssss.............

Comment: Not a downvoter but your question is very specific, you provide overly complicated stored procedures that mean nothing to anyone except yourself, you don't provide table schema nor do you provide example data. Also this problem could just solved by debugging using `print` to output all the parameters being passed around to each stored procedure and the values that are returned, and then drilling into the problematic area and adding more debugging `print` code.

Comment: @Seph i just wanted to show the Hierarchy nothing else and the way i have done that, if i have done it in wrong way the experts can tell me the right way to do .. so i have pasted code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you -

**1.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateOnly]
(
      @Scheduleid BIGINT
    , @Contactid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @ScheduleDate DATETIME
    , @StartTime VARCHAR(20)
    , @EndTime VARCHAR(20)
    , @Location BIGINT
    , @Area BIGINT
    , @Room BIGINT
    , @Enddate DATETIME
    , @CurrentTime DATETIME
    , @ModifiedBy UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @schedulefileidNew BIGINT
)
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE dbo.tblUserScheduleNew
    SET     
          Contactid = @Contactid 
        , ScheduleDate = @ScheduleDate 
        , StartTime = @StartTime 
        , EndTime = @EndTime 
        , location = @Location 
        , Area = @Area 
        , Room = @Room 
        , LastModifiedDate = @CurrentTime 
        , EndDate = @Enddate 
        , ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy 
        , ScheduleFileId = NULLIF(@schedulefileidNew, 0)
    WHERE ScheduleID = @Scheduleid 
        AND IsDeleted = 0
        AND isActive = 1

    RETURN 1

END
```

**2.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate] 
(
      @StartDatePassed DATETIME
    , @EndDatePassed DATETIME
    , @StartTimePassed VARCHAR(20)
    , @EndTimePassed VARCHAR(20)
    , @CurrentDateTime DATETIME
    , @Scheduleid BIGINT
    , @Contactid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @Location BIGINT
    , @Area BIGINT
    , @Room BIGINT
    , @ModifiedBy UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
    , @schedulefileidNew BIGINT
)
AS BEGIN

    IF 
          CONVERT(DATE, @StartDatePassed, 101) > CONVERT(DATE, @CurrentDateTime, 101) 
        AND
          CONVERT(DATE, @EndDatePassed, 101) > CONVERT(DATE, @CurrentDateTime, 101) 
        AND
          CONVERT(DATE, @EndDatePassed, 101) > CONVERT(DATE, @StartDatePassed, 101)

    BEGIN    

        DECLARE @ResultForInsertUpdate VARCHAR(200)

        EXEC @ResultForInsertUpdate = dbo.proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateOnly 
                @Scheduleid
            ,   @Contactid
            ,   @StartDatePassed
            ,   @StartTimePassed
            ,   @EndTimePassed
            ,   @Location
            ,   @Area
            ,   @Room
            ,   @EndDatePassed
            ,   @CurrentDateTime
            ,   @ModifiedBy
            ,   @schedulefileidNew

        RETURN @ResultForInsertUpdate

    END
    ELSE BEGIN

        RETURN 2

    END

END
```

**3.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_tblUserScheduleNewUpdateWithAllRoomsOption 
(
    @StartDatePassed DATETIME,
    @EndDatePassed DATETIME,
    @StartTimePassed VARCHAR(20),
    @EndTimePassed VARCHAR(20),
    @CurrentDateTime DATETIME,
    @Scheduleid BIGINT,
    @Contactid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @Location BIGINT,
    @Area BIGINT,
    @Room BIGINT,
    @ModifiedBy UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @schedulefileidNew BIGINT,
    @OldStartDate DATETIME,
    @OldEndDate DATETIME,
    @OldStartTime VARCHAR(20),
    @OldEndTime VARCHAR(20),
    @OldContactid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @OldLocation BIGINT,
    @OldArea BIGINT,
    @OldRoom BIGINT
)
AS BEGIN

    DECLARE 
          @row_count INT
        , @intFlag INT = 0
        , @locationIdForLoop BIGINT
        , @AreaIdForLoop BIGINT
        , @RoomIdForLoop BIGINT
        , @ResultForInsertUpdate INT = 1

    CREATE TABLE #tempTable (RowNum INT, LocationId BIGINT, AreaId BIGINT, RoomId BIGINT)

    IF @Area = 0 AND @Room = 0 BEGIN

        INSERT INTO #tempTable (RowNum, LocationId, AreaId, RoomId)
        SELECT
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LocationId DESC) RowNum
            ,   LocationId
            ,   AreaId
            ,   RoomId
        FROM dbo.tblroomnew a
        WHERE a.AreaId IN (
            SELECT b.AreaId
            FROM dbo.tblareanew b
            WHERE b.LocationId = @Location
        )

        SELECT 
              @row_count = COUNT(1) 
            , @intFlag = 1
        FROM #tempTable

        WHILE (@intFlag <= @row_count) BEGIN

            SELECT 
                  @locationIdForLoop = LocationId
                , @AreaIdForLoop = AreaId
                , @RoomIdForLoop = RoomId
            FROM #tempTable
            WHERE RowNum=@intFlag

            IF @ResultForInsertUpdate = 1 BEGIN
                IF EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM dbo.tbluserschedulenew
                    WHERE 
                        CONVERT(DATETIME,ScheduleDate,101)=CONVERT(DATETIME,@OldStartDate,101) AND
                        CONVERT(DATETIME,EndDate,101)=CONVERT(DATETIME,@OldEndDate,101) AND
                        CONVERT(TIME,StartTime,108)=CONVERT(TIME,@OldStartTime,108) AND
                        CONVERT(TIME,EndTime,108)=CONVERT(TIME,@OldEndTime,108) AND contactid=@OldContactid
                        AND location=@OldLocation 
                        AND Area=@OldArea 
                        AND Room=@OldRoom
                )
                BEGIN

                    PRINT 'Update First record'
                    EXEC @ResultForInsertUpdate=proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate 
                            @StartDatePassed
                        ,   @EndDatePassed
                        ,   @StartTimePassed
                        ,   @EndTimePassed
                        ,   @CurrentDateTime
                        ,   @Scheduleid
                        ,   @Contactid
                        ,   @locationIdForLoop
                        ,   @AreaIdForLoop
                        ,   @RoomIdForLoop
                        ,   @ModifiedBy
                        ,   @schedulefileidNew

                    RETURN @ResultForInsertUpdate

                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN

                    EXEC proc_tblUserScheduleNewLatestInsert    
                            @Contactid
                        ,   @StartDatePassed
                        ,   @StartTimePassed
                        ,   @EndTimePassed
                        ,   @locationIdForLoop
                        ,   @AreaIdForLoop
                        ,   @RoomIdForLoop
                        ,   @EndDatePassed
                        ,   @ModifiedBy
                        ,   0
                        ,   @CurrentDateTime

                END
            END
            ELSE BEGIN

                RETURN @ResultForInsertUpdate

            END
            SELECT @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
        END
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        IF @Area != 0 AND @Room = 0 BEGIN

            INSERT INTO #tempTable (RowNum, LocationId, AreaId, RoomId)
            SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LocationId DESC) RowNum
                ,   LocationId
                ,   AreaId
                ,   RoomId
            FROM dbo.tblroomnew a

            SELECT @row_count = COUNT(1)
            FROM #tempTable

        END
        ELSE BEGIN

            EXEC dbo.proc_tblUserScheduleNewFutureUpdate 
                        @StartDatePassed
                    ,   @EndDatePassed
                    ,   @StartTimePassed
                    ,   @EndTimePassed
                    ,   @CurrentDateTime
                    ,   @Scheduleid
                    ,   @Contactid
                    ,   @location
                    ,   @Area
                    ,   @Room
                    ,   @ModifiedBy
                    ,   @schedulefileidNew
        END

    END

END
```

Comment: thanks we have tried return and its working for us... thanks alot

Comment: I'm glad I was helpful. In some places I simplified the code which in theory should have led to increasing the speed of executing sp. To understand the root of the your problem, I formatted your script with our product dbForge SQL Complete, that you may be interested in: http://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/sqlcomplete/download.html