# Not able to get the stored procedure's result in variable in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, variables, sql-server-2008-r2

i have a Hierarchy of stored procedures calling one in another as below:

```
1
 2
  3
```

Now what i am doing is: 
first of all i am showing the 1st level sp .

```
Create proc proc_test3
(
@Id uniqueidentifier,
@value varchar(100)
)
as
declare @Outputvalue varchar(100)
if @Id='2'
begin
exec @Outputvalue= proc_test2 @Id @value
select @Outputvalue
end
```

Here is the second level :

```
Create proc proc_test2
(
@Id uniqueidentifier,
@value varchar(100)
)
as
declare @Outputvalue varchar(100)
if @Id='2'
begin
exec @Outputvalue= proc_test1 @Id @value
select @Outputvalue
end
```

and here is last 3rd level :

```
Create proc proc_test1
(
@Id uniqueidentifier,
@value varchar(100)
)
as
update tblsample set value=@value where id=@Id
select 1
```

I have paste just an example but in-actual my code is much complex to read, so i have implemented it in some simpler way so that every can understand it easily,

Now what is my problem:
every time i got @Outputvalue=0 when i execute the "**proc_test3**", please help me so that i can come out from this prob, if i am doing the things in some wrong way please let me know the right way, please help me resolve the issue.

Comment: @GSerg hmm ok but how to overcome that can you please explain that answer to me or how can i solve the issue now,..... please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use RETURN construction -

```
CREATE PROC proc_test3
(
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @value VARCHAR(100)
)
AS BEGIN

    IF @Id = '2' BEGIN

        DECLARE @Outputvalue VARCHAR(100)
        EXEC @Outputvalue = dbo.proc_test2 @Id, @value
        RETURN @Outputvalue

    END

END


CREATE PROC proc_test2
(
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @value VARCHAR(100)
)
AS BEGIN

    IF @Id='2' BEGIN

        DECLARE @Outputvalue VARCHAR(100)
        EXEC @Outputvalue= proc_test1 @Id, @value
        RETURN @Outputvalue

    END

END


CREATE PROC proc_test1
(
    @Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @value VARCHAR(100)
)
AS BEGIN

    UPDATE tblsample 
    SET value=@value 
    WHERE id=@Id

    RETURN 1

END
```

Comment: @Raman, if you could undelete this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16211786/not-able-to-get-the-stored-procedures-result-in-variable, I would try to help you.

Comment: ok.. its being asked by my junior developer.. i dont know if he elaborated it well. by the way i am asking him to undeleted the questiopn